# Access to JavaScript root level object THIS keyword value

Tags: javascript

On my basic JavaScript object example below for how I often structure my JavaScript projects.

in my `TestApp.init()` function I call this function `this.cache.cacheFuncOne();` which is another function that is 1 level deeper inside another object named `cache`.

Inside `this.cache.cacheFuncOne();` I try to access the property on the main object `this.prop1` which results in undefined.

When I access `this.prop1` from other functions that are not 1 level deeper nested in another object, then it works as expected and shows the value.

So I have come to realize that in the `cache{}` object, `this` keyword is not the same value as `this` on the root level object.

Based on this simple demo, how would I access the root level `this` value within the `cache{}` object below?

```js
var TestApp = {
  prop1: 'property1',

  init: function() {
    this.cache.cacheFuncOne();
    alert(this.prop1);
  },

  funcOne: function() {

  },

  funcTwo: function() {

  },

  cache: {

    cacheFuncOne: function() {
      alert(this.prop1);
    },
  }

}

TestApp.init();
```

Comment: Since it's a singleton object, use `TestApp.prop1`.

Comment: I think you can use .bind(this) to get the this value of a parent scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is either [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). Both of them are part of the [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)'s prototype, and their first argument is the object that will be the `this` inside the function.

So in your case, you could do this:

```
// ...
init: function() {
  this.cache.cacheFuncOne.call(this);
  alert(this.prop1);
}
// ...
```

Also, if you use ES6, you can just use the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 1):

Can you use ES6/ES2015? If so you can just use arrow functions

```
cacheFuncOne: () => {
  alert(this.prop1);
},
```

`this` will refer to the object with `prop1`.

---

Another option is to use [`bind(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
cacheFuncOne: function () {
  alert(this.prop1);
}.bind(this),
```